# React JSX Dynamic SVG Translate Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm new to React and trying to do a dynamic Svg Transition where I translate the Position of a Group according to the current Component State. For some reason I get the Error Message:

```
 DOMPropertyOperations.js:139 Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected 
'(', "translate:(100 100)".
```

Here is the render function:

```
render() {
    let turns = Route.Leg.map((turn) => <circle cx={turn.to.location.latitude} cy={turn.to.location.longitude} r="5"></circle>)
    let legs = Route.Leg.map((leg) => <line x1={leg.from.location.latitude} y1={leg.from.location.longitude} x2={leg.to.location.latitude} y2={leg.to.location.longitude} stroke="black"></line>)

    let move = "translate:(" + this.state.pos.location.latitude + " " + this.state.pos.location.longitude + ")";

    return (
        <div>
            <svg width="800px" height="800px">
                <circle cx="400" cy="400" r="10"></circle>
                <g transform={move}>
                    {turns}
                    {legs}
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The lines and circles are drawn correctly, and when I log the "move" variable and looks correct every time the dom updates. When I hardcode the translate it also works. Does someone have an idea what is wrong here, or am I just missing something? Cheers in advance

Comment: There should not be a `:` in your `move` string. Try `"translate(" + this.state.pos.location.latitude + " " + this.state.pos.location.longitude + ")"`

Comment: go dammit I double checked like 10 times :D works thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As says in the error `Expected (',...`

```
// Look down, there is no ":" character in css syntax. And check for ","
let move = "translate(" + this.state.pos.location.latitude + "," + this.state.pos.location.longitude + ")";
```

That's because of you are using wrong syntax. You should use `translate(...` not `translate:(...`.
Also you should comma seperate values inside `translate`